# AR motion design exhibition in the real space of the city

Tags: javascript, android, camera, augmented-reality, aframe

I'm having trouble finding information on the website about how to add a camera and display real-world space in A-Frame.

I have a project related to a zoo, where extinct animals will roam around the real enclosures in AR mode. But I'm stuck and don't understand how to add a connection with the camera in my project.

I would also like to add image target tracking, like in SPARK AR. Is there such a possibility or any tutorials, manuals, anything you could recommend?

Thank you for your help!

Best regards,
Victoria Tomadze

Comment: Try [mindAr](https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/) or [arjs](https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js/). Both are addons for `a-frame` which should help with image / marker tracking. There are also a couple of examples [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/ar/).